# Trying to exit out of a function in Django in order to render correct html page name

Tags: django, python-3.x

Please take a look at my code here. The problem I am running into is I can't get the if statement to render my page with the correct title to the page. It renders fine (smith.html), but the url remains "login" displaying in the browser which is the url title linked to the user_login view. Everything works, except for this one thing.

```
def user_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form": form}
    next_url = request.GET.get('next')

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        #print(username,password)
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        for user in 'username','password':
            if ('username','password') == ('jsmith1','smithproject'):
                break
            return Smith_Project(request)
```

I put the break in there to try and get it to exit out of the user_login function so that it can cleanly execute the Smith_Project function (hence display the url name 'smith' which is assigned to the Smith_Project function in views.py. But, that didn't work, still returns the page (after user is authenticated as 'jsmith1' with 'smithproject' as password)as 'login'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your view. I think that the biggest problem is that you have not realised that the urls (e.g. `/login/`), views e.g. `user_login`, and templates (e.g. `templates/smith.html`) are all decoupled.

The template e.g. `templates/smith.html` is separate from the url, you would not expect to see it in the url bar.

If you want to redirect the user from `/login/` to another url, you should return a redirect response.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect('/smith/')
```

You would then need to add a url pattern for `/smith/` to your `urls.py`.

Here's are some more couple of issues with your view:

You have authenticated the username and password, but you have not logged them in. See [how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for more details.

```
for user in 'username','password':
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. This code will loop twice. First, with `user='username'`, then with `user='password'`.

```
if ('username','password') == ('jsmith1','smithproject'):
```

This is comparing the string 'username' (not the variable) to the string 'jsmith1', and the string 'password' (not the variable) to the string 'smithproject'. Therefore it will always return `False`. I hope you just have the password 'smithproject' hardcoded for testing - in production you should avoid having passwords in your code.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair. Obviously, I am a newb and I appreciate your input very much. I definitely have a lot to learn. Thank you for taking the time to post an answer.